# Entire function with $f(0)=1$ and $f(1-1/n^2)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Can we find an entire function with the properties $f(0)=1$ and $f(\frac{n^2-1)}{n^2})=0$

We could have applied the Weirestrass Theorem to find such entire function with prescribed zeros.But , 
the problem is:
The sequence of roots of $f(z)$
$\{\frac{1-n^2}{n^2}\}_{n\geq2}$ has an accumulation point which is $1$. Thus we can not apply Weirestrass.

Another way I tried to approach is :

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$$

$f(0)=a_0=1$ and $f(1-1/n^2) =1+ a_1 (1-1/n^2)+a_2 (1-1/n^2)^2+......$

If we choose large $n$ then we get $f(1)=1+a_1+a_2+a_3+.....   =0$ is this possible to have. I am kind of confuse on my work.

Any hints?

Comment: What important theorem mentions accumulation points?

Comment: The question in your post is different from the one in the title.

Comment: Weirestrass Theorem for finding entire function with prescribed zeros having no accumulation point . And sorry for typo

Comment: And far far earlier, there was another theorem that mentioned accumulation points of zeros.

Comment: Although no entire function exists, you can find such a function on $B(0,1)$, vanishing with order $1$ at each of those points. However, it cannot vanish say with order $n$ at $1-1/n^2$, since it would violate the Blaschke condition $\sum \mathfrak d(z)(1-|z|)<+\infty$.

Comment: Yes , identity theorem of holomorphich function mention about the accumulation points

Answer (score 1):

Since $\left \{ 1-1/n^2 \right \}_{n=2}^\infty$ has a finite accumulation point, your function is uniquely determined by its values there. Here the values are all zero, so one holomorphic function with those values is the zero function. Since the function is uniquely determined by those values, no function with all your specified properties exists.

Comment: So $f(z)=0$ identically. but does not $f(0)=1$ disturb to apply this idea?

Comment: @mp100 Right. ${}$